# onCreateView() in Fragment is not called immediately, even after FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()

Tags: java, android, fragment

I read that if we need to create fragment immediately, we have to call `executePendingTransactions()` method on `FragmentManager`. Well, that's what I'm trying to do. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.layout.fragmentContainer, new MyFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    foo(); // It is called before MyFragment's onCreateView()
}
```

I'd like to know why `foo()` method is called BEFORE `MyFragment`'s `onCreateView()`. As you see, I'm calling `executePendingTransactions()` in UI Thread as it should be. I'm not messing here with threads at all.

Comment: Can you attach a boolean to execute pending txns like this `boolean val = fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` and see what it yields once foo is called while debugging.

Comment: Hi, is there any news on this issue? I'm facing same problem and cannot find the solution. If you've solved it, can you share the solution, please?

Comment: @Haspemulator Unfortunately not - I finally decided to use completely different approach.

Comment: I'm still interessted why it works in the onStart and not in the onCreate. Anyone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I found that if I ran the same fragmentTransaction code from within the onStart method, the execution worked as expected. I do not know enough about the Android view lifecycle to know why this is the case though.

```
public void onStart() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.layout.fragmentContainer, new MyFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    foo(); // Should now work correctly
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I only want to add one useful feature - use onPostCreate() instead of onStart() to avoid fragment creation every time onStart() is called. Cheers!

Comment: Wow I can't believe this worked. Android is really confusing
edit: whaaaa no this onStart is called in situations where oncreate isn't, like returning from a camera intent...